# PHP Can't get value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I can't echo $graphObject['location']['name'] from this array:

```
array(6) {
  ["birthday"]=>
  string(10) "09/09/1989"
  ["location"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(15) "110526485641433"
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "Augsburg, Germany"
  }
  ["locale"]=>
  string(5) "de_DE"
  ["timezone"]=>
  int(2)
  ["updated_time"]=>
  string(24) "2014-06-20T08:24:24+0000"
  ["verified"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

How to do that right?

Comment: `$graphObject['location']->['name']` ?

Comment: $graphObject['location']->{name}

Comment: $graphObject['location']=>['name'] or $graphObject['location']->['name'] isn't working

Comment: $graphObject['location']->{'name'}; worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$graphObject['location']` is not an array.

You can check that it says `["location"]=>object(stdClass).`

It's and stdClass Object, so you can fetch the variable like this:

```
$graphObject['location']->name;
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $graphObject['location']->name;
```